# ¿Cómo imprimir consulta ejecutada con PHP PDO?

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una función donde se realiza un `insert` y quiero imprimir la consulta ya con los datos que se envían desde un formulario.

Esta es mi función:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (tutor_name, relationship_tutor, date_of_birth_of_tutor, occupation_tutor, phone_tutor, email_tutor, sex_tutor) VALUES (:tutor_name, :relationship_tutor, :date_of_birth_of_tutor, :occupation_tutor, :phone_tutor, :email_tutor, :sex_tutor)");
            
    public function addUser($infoUser)
        {   
                $statement->bindValue('tutor_name', $infoUser['tutor_name']);
                $statement->bindValue('relationship_tutor', $infoUser['relationship_tutor']);
                $statement->bindValue('date_of_birth_of_tutor', $infoUser['date_of_birth_of_tutor']);
                $statement->bindValue('occupation_tutor', $infoUser['occupation_tutor']);
                $statement->bindValue('phone_tutor', $infoUser['phone_tutor']);
                $statement->bindValue('email_tutor', $infoUser['email_tutor']);
                $statement->bindValue('sex_tutor', $infoUser['sex_tutor']);
    
                $statement->execute();
            }
```

Es decir, **¿es posible que en pantalla me muestre el insert con los datos ya establecidos?**

Ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO (campo1,campo2,campo3) value ('dato1','dato2','dato3')
```

Comment: Dudo que tal como lo tienes ahora te funcione nada, por varios motivos: 1) Dentro de la función no tienes puesta la línea donde está el $statement asignado, por lo tanto no sabe lo que es realmente, 2) No ejecutas la función `addUser` en ningún momento (al menos no lo has puesto en tu pregunta).  Si lo que quieres es asegurarte que la consulta está bien empieza arreglando eso, sino no sacarás nada en claro.

Comment: puedes hacer un `$statement->debugDumpParams();` para ver el resultado de los parametros;}

Comment: Por otra parte, la respuesta  tu pregunta concreta es **no**, al menos no mediante el objeto PDO, pues no tiene ninguna forma de mostrarla entre sus funciones.  Otra cosa seria que lo simularas paralelamente agregando las variables a un string y lo mostraras o guardaras tambien, o que fueras al log de tu base de datos a ver si alli aparece y la puedes ver completa.

Comment: Vaya, pues sí que la hay... esto es increible, aquí el que no quiera aprender es porque no quiere :-) Gracias @Bryro por el aporte!  (pero en el fondo yo no estaba tan equivocado, pues eso pertenece a una clase PDOStatement y no una clase PDO)

Comment: @masterguru `PDOStatement` es una clase dependiente de [la clase PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php). Sin ésta, aquella no tendría razón de ser, de hecho, métodos como `execute()`, `bindParam()` y todos los `fetch` que se usan para leer los resultados de la consultas son métodos de [la clase PDOStatement](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php), pero se usan siempre partiendo de PDO, que conecta, prepara y luego le pasa el testigo a su clase ayudadora.

Comment: @A.Cedano sí sí, gracias por la explicación, más o menos eso lo sabia, pero buscando una respuesta solo me fijé en las funciones de PDO y no se me ocurrió mirar las de PDOStatement, y las otras cosas que encontré en otros sitios (el SO en inglés) decian que no era posible (de hecho no es posible hacer lo que pide la pregunta ni con PDO ni con PDOStatement directamente, se tendria que elaborar a partir de ahi capturando esa salida en todo caso)

Comment: @masterguru claro. Y es que tampoco le veo demasiado sentido a la pregunta (salvo que se esté intentando construir algo así como un descifrador de instrucciones SQL). Algo  más simple sería que OP construya en origen un parámetro con este estilo: `$params=array('campo1'=>'valor1', 'campo2'=>'valor2', 'campoN'=>'valorN');` y si quiere rehacer la consulta original que se ejecutó, con `$params` lo tiene a punto, al tiempo que usa también `$params` para ejecutar su consulta con toda seguridad. Se ahorraría varias líneas de código también en la vinculación y demás.